# Use array to store matrices

Tags: r, arrays

I have three matrices, say `X1`, `X2` and `X3` with the same dimension `100-by-3`. Now I want to store them in an array. I tried

```
X <- array(c(X1,X2,X3), dim=c(100,3,3))
```

But it seems that `X[,,1]` is not equal to `X1`. So I wonder how to achieve this?

Comment: I tried with a dummy example where: `X1 <- matrix(1:300, nrow = 100);X2 <- matrix(301:600, nrow = 100);X3 <- matrix(601:900, nrow = 100)`. When I use your code `identical(X[,,1], X1)` is TRUE. So don't get what you mean. Can you provide an example that you think is off?

Comment: @Sonji: What do you mean? arrays do exist. It depends what you need to do.

Comment: You could add a third dimension by storing the matrices in a list: `mylist <- list(X1, X2, X3)`  Then access a specific matrix by its list element.  E.g. `mylist[[1]]` is `X1`.

Comment: @Sonji comment makes me wish I could downvote comments. Sonji, please delete - it is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `abind` package for this:

```
X1 = matrix(1, 3, 4)
X2 = matrix(2, 3, 4)
X3 = matrix(3, 3, 4)

library(abind)
X = abind(X1, X2, X3, along = 3)

X[, , 1]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
```

---

But, G. Grothendieck is correct - your method works as well. Here it is demonstrated on my sample data:

```
X <- array(c(X1,X2,X3), dim=c(dim(X1),3))
X[, , 1]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1

X[, , 2]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2    2
# [3,]    2    2    2    2

# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.  Check what you did.

```
m <- matrix(1:8, 2, 4)
m3 <- array(c(m, 10 * m, 100 * m), c(2, 4, 3))

m3[,,1]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    3    5    7
## [2,]    2    4    6    8

m3[,,2]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   10   30   50   70
## [2,]   20   40   60   80

m3[,,3]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]  100  300  500  700
## [2,]  200  400  600  800
```